# Fixed height elements force other elements to zero height on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, css-grid

If the total height of the table gaps and grid items exceeds the 85% height allotted to `content-right`, for some reason `main-nav` begins to lose its height until its height becomes `0` despite `flex-shrink: 0`.

**Does anybody know what's going on??**

```css
:root {
  --left-width: 25%;
  --right-width: 75%;
  --gap: 25px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 15;
  flex-shrink: 0; /**/
  display: flex;
}

#nav-left {
  width: var(--left-width);
  height: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
}

#nav-right {
  width: var(--right-width);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 var(--gap);
  background: pink;
}

#main-content {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 85;
  flex-shrink: 0; /**/
  display: flex;
}

#content-left {
  width: var(--left-width);
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

#content-right {
  width: var(--right-width);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 var(--gap);
  background: skyblue;
}

#grid-cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: var(--gap);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
}

.grid-item {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='main-nav'>
    <div id='nav-left'></div>
    <div id='nav-right'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='main-content'>
    <div id='content-left'>
    </div>
    <div id='content-right'>
      <div id='grid-cont'>
        <div class='grid-item'></div> <!-- issue with grid items and main-nav on firefox -->
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>

        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>

        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>

        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>

        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>

        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
        <div class='grid-item'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to define heights in `#main-nav` and `#main-content`. Note that your layout seems to work fine in Firefox and Edge.

Comment: @Michael_B their heights are set via the `flex` property??

Comment: Chrome / Safari don't take that.

Comment: @Michael_B neither does firefox apparently??? its not working in firefox on my end

Comment: Try setting a fixed `height` or `flex-basis` on any parent of a child with percentage height. Does that fix the behavior?

Comment: @Michael_B ive tried that already. it doesnt work. god we r almost in 2020 and browsers are still blind to one another :(

Comment: I am using chrome and I don't see any element with 0 height, what I am missing?

Comment: So maybe I'm not fully understanding the problem. Can you provide more details or post illustrations?

Comment: `#main-nav` and `#main-nav` are flex items with `flex-basis: 0` (`height: 0`). @TemaniAfif

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry, the issue is on firefox. i forgot to specify that

Comment: @Michael_B yes and then he set the flex-grow to have the 15/85 proportion which is what I am seeing .. visually no element is having a height computed to 0

Comment: @TemaniAfif the issue is on ***firefox!!!!!***

Comment: It matters when the children have percentage heights. @TemaniAfif

Comment: @Michael_B this is a min-height issue then .. adding `min-height:0` to `main-content` will fix this and we will have the same behavior as chrome (not sure if percentage height have to do something here)

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's it!! wow. so `min-height: 0` kind of acts like `flex-shrink: 1` for `main-content` and `flex-shrink: 0` for `main-nav`???

Comment: not exactly, check the duplicate and read the notes at the end of the accepted answer to better understand

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks. why cnat we just have one browser for all desktops and one browser for all mobiles

Comment: @Anthony it won't be funny in this case :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif what wont be funny??

Comment: to have different browser and a lot of issues, this is fun ;) if everything is static and there is no bug/issues then it will boring, no? :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif not boring at all. it would be way more efficient and fun because you could spend time actually building stuff instead of fixing stuff